# Laravel Dusk: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, laravel-dusk, laravel-8

I'm following the instructions on how to run browser tests from here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk on a fresh install of Laravel using Homestead running on a VirtualBox vm.

When I try to run `artisan dusk` however, it fails and tells me it can't find the Chrome binary.

```
1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`
```

Googling tells me to install the Chrome Binary (of course) but that appears to have been done already. Scrolling up the CLI, I see the following from when I ran `dusk install`.

```
Downloading ChromeDriver binaries...
ChromeDriver binaries successfully installed for version 86.0.4240.22.
```

So is there something else I need to install, or do I need to tell dusk where to look for the binary, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Did you enable the `webdriver` feature? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#laravel-dusk

Answer (score 1):

As you already have ChromeDrive you maybe just need to start it

```sh
./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux
```

Comment: It's worked again after months. 
It's ./vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-win.exe for WIndows OS

Answer (score 1):

In order to run laravel dusk you need to have google chrome installed.

That being said if you are using Homestead simply enable the webdriver feature in your Homestead.yaml configuration:

```
features:
- webdriver: true
```

Remember that after enabling the webdriver feature, you need to reboot/provison your homestead to load the config change.

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Sources:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#laravel-dusk

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/homestead#laravel-dusk

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to have chrome installed. That's it. Not chrome dev or canary or any of those alternave versions, you need to have the *real* chrome browser installed. I had chrome dev installed and I kept getting this error until I downloaded the **actual chrome**.